# Gradle 8.7 cannot find installed JDK 22 in IntelliJ

Tags: java, windows, gradle, intellij-idea, build

I have created a new project with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version 2024.1. This version supports the new Java 22 (openjdk-22) version. But when I reload my Gradle project, it shows this error:

```
Unsupported Gradle JVM.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 22 and Gradle 8.7.
Possible solutions:

- Use Java 21 as Gradle JVM: Open Gradle settings
- Upgrade to Gradle 8.5 and re-sync
```

AND THIS:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 66
> Unsupported class file major version 66

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

CONFIGURE FAILED in 69ms
```

Under "project structure" I have selected the installed Java 22 SDK. Also, all Modules are of the SDK Default Language Level.

These are my Gradle properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

and this is my build.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_22
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_22

}
dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Gradle 8.7 does not run on Java 22

The problem is not that IntelliJ-IDEA doesn't support Java 22. The problem is that Gradle does not run on Java 22 (it only supports building projects for Java 22 but must be run with Java 21 maximum).

From the [Gradle 8.7 release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html#support-for-building-projects-with-java-22):

> **Support for building projects with Java 22**
>
> Gradle now supports using Java 22 for compiling, testing, and starting other Java programs. Selecting a language version is done using toolchains.
>
> You cannot run Gradle 8.7 itself with Java 22 because Groovy still needs to support JDK 22. However, future versions are expected to provide this support.

Comment: But that's strange, because it works with another friend. I try to run test classes and it works for him, but not for me. Although we both have the same version of Intellij and Gradle.
Once when I built this, I hovered over JJavaVersion.VERSION_22 in build.gradle.kts and it said gradle-8.4.jar. Although the .zip of version 8.4 was in the gradle.properties. It seems to me that Intellji takes a Gradle version from my PC and not the one from the project. I have already deleted the .gradle folder from my Windows user, but it didn't help either.